# Weaker version of the Borel lemma for vector-valued functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, asymptotics, locally-convex-spaces, taylor-series

Borel's lemma for Frechét-spaces $V$ says:

> (i) For every $(v_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in V^\mathbb{N}$ there exists a smooth $f: \mathbb{R} \to V$ such that
> $$f^{(j)}(0) = v_j.$$

For general locally convex spaces this theorem is false, see e.g. [Borel Lemma for vector-valued functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54661/borel-lemma-for-vector-valued-functions).
One then could try to restate the "lemma" in the following weaker way:

> (ii) For every $(v_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in V^\mathbb{N}$ there exists an $f: \mathbb{R} \to V$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$
> $$f(t) = \sum_{j=0}^N \frac{t^j}{j!} v_j + o(|t^N|).$$

This weaker notion of the derivative is called the Peano derivative here: [Taylor $k$-differentiability of a real function at a point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344698/taylor-k-differentiability-of-a-real-function-at-a-point). I couldn't find anything regarding spaces having property (ii) in the literature.

So my question: Is there a space $V$ such that (ii) holds but (i) doesn't?

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes, you're right. Thanks!